# How to set custom height of a child in ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have several items in a list view which are same in size but I want to show one text button at the end, I want the splash of the text button, to limit only around the text like a normal button, but in this situation, the splash is becoming same as the height of other children. I have tried many things like wrapping the text inside *SizedBox*, *ConstrainedBox*, *Padding*, *Container*, but nothing worked. Please help me

```
SizedBox(
          height: 250,
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            itemCount: products.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              if (index == products.length - 1) {
                return ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 40, minWidth: 100),
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('View All'),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return ProductWidget(product: products[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
```

[image: Current Situation]

> This video is not showing the thing I want, the video is showing the
> problem, which I am facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use `Center(child:TextButton`

```dart
return Center(
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('View All'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question, I want the splash height limited to close to the text (View all) of button

Comment: My bad, updated

Comment: This is working, can you please explain the reason behind it ?

Comment: On flutter,  size goes up, so you are tricking the UI with another widget . You can find more [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you `TextButton` with `Container` instead of `ConstrainedBox` and set its `alignment` to `center` like this:

```
Container(//<--- add this
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 40, minWidth: 100),
    alignment: Alignment.center,//<--- add this
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('View All'),
    ),
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Container and give height Instead of using ConstrainedBox